# Why is Chrome telling me this function is "not a function"?

Tags: javascript, function

I have an immediately invoked JS function that removes all empty paragraphs from a WordPress site I'm working on:

```
//Remove empty paragraph tags
(function () {
  const pTag = document.querySelectorAll("p");

  pTag.forEach((p) => {
    if (p.innerHTML == "&nbsp;") {
      p.remove();
    }
  });
})();
```

Using Sentry to track errors, I'm getting `TypeError pTag.forEach is not a function` on some sessions, others seem to work fine. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: You must be using an old browser

Comment: @Certain, that wouldn't explain why it works intermittently.

Comment: @tao Some are using old browsers - others aren't. The error will arise on those using old (or incompatible) browsers

Comment: Yep, just read about what `wp-sentry` is. Sackadelic, the solution is to provide a `.forEach` polyfill.

Comment: Thank you. I'll do some research into that.